# Query Posts Via WordPress URL

Tags: custom-field, filters, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I wanted to learn more about querying post types and their custom fields in WordPress. I've got two questions...

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/) on Advanced Custom Fields and am trying to understand what is happening here. This is placed in my theme's function file.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( isset($_GET['type']) ) {
        $type = explode(',', $_GET['type']);

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'type',
            'value'     => $type,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return; // always return
}
```

Now I understand this is somehow allowing the URL to alter the query based on its custom field (in this case `type`) and values that are assigned to this post. But how exactly is it working?

My second question is, when I pass this query in my URL like so:

> `http://example.com/cars?type=coupe,hatchback`

it returns all Coupe and Hatchback cars – which is great! This seems to work because my custom field (`type`) only accepts one value. A car has to be either a Coupe or a Hatchback – it can't be both.

On the other hand, some of my custom fields (take `for`, for example) can hold more than one value. My `for` custom field can actually take up to five values ("him", "her", "families" etc). For some reason, that code above doesn't play nice when assigned to custom field (like `for`) that can have multiple values. This doesn't work, at all:

> `http://example.com/cars?for=him,her`

Any ideas why that is and what I have to do to get it to work?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Matching multiple values by running the `LIKE` query:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if( is_admin() ) { return; }

if( isset($_GET['type']) ) {                        
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'type',
        'value' => '"' . $_GET['type'] . '"',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
}
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

return;
}
```

Comment: There is code involved that you have not posted. In fact, what you posted wouldn't do anything at all except take up a tiny bit of processing power.

To work, that code needs to be hooked into `pre_get_posts`, or used as part of a new `WP_Query` or passed to `query_posts`. Don't ever do the latter. 

Most of what you need is likely on the the Codex page for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and in the PHP docs.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've updated it with the full code block.

Comment: If this is an ACF checkbox field (assuming this is related to your other questions), those values are saved as serialized data in a single field, so you can't make that work with a meta query. in hindsight, that was probably your issue with those other questions, sorry it didn't dawn on me sooner.

Comment: @Milo That makes sense. Though, I did see a [post on the ACF forum][1] from the plugin author that mentioned sending multiple values through like this: `website.com?foo=bar|bar2|bar3` and exploding via the '|'. Would that be possible?

  [1]: http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/custom-archive-filter-multiple-choice/

Comment: I don't see how that's any different from passing them comma-separated. anyway, the issue is that the data is saved in a format that only php "understands", so MySQL can't query that data.

Comment: But since this data is saved as a serialized array, shouldn't the LIKE query match against the custom field value in the serialized array? Edited original question above with my example.

Comment: Only if you're querying for a single term, it won't match multiple terms.

Comment: @Milo Is there any way to convert that serialized array? Or a solution to match multiple terms? Or is it simply impossible?

Comment: use an ACF taxonomy field (or just the built-in WordPress taxonomy UI) and do a `tax_query` instead.

Comment: I don't think the Taxonomy Field is an option since there's still more fields that accept multiple values (Repeater Field, Checkbox Field) I'm going to need to get multiple terms from. The plugin author seems convinced it's possible. See [here](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/custom-archive-filter-multiple-choice/#post-9323) and [here](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/filtering-archives-using-checkbox-custom-fields/#post-9561). Confused what to think.

Comment: and you can't use taxonomies for those as well? you could otherwise possibly do it with lots of separate LIKE queries, but you'll probably be wondering why your server is suddenly so painfully slow to generate these queries, LIKE is very inefficient compared to an IN

Comment: @Milo As a separate answer, please.